# Why does the Perl 6 sequence 'A' ... 'AA' have only one element?

Tags: sequence, raku

Today I noticed that the sequence `'A' ... 'AA'` contains only one element:

```
> 'A' ... 'AA'
(A)
```

I thought it would contain 27: the alphabet plus the final `AA`.

If I explicitly provide a generator, it does:

```
> 'A', *.succ ... 'AA'
(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA)
```

The docs say that the default generator is either `*.succ` or `*.pred` depending on how the end points compare.  But:

```
> 'A' cmp 'AA'
Less
```

So it seems I should be getting the `*.succ` generator by default.  I'm definitely not getting the `*.pred` generator:

```
> 'A', *.pred ... 'AA'
Decrement out of range
  in whatevercode  at <unknown file> line 1
```

What's going on here?

Comment: weird... `('A' ... 'YY').elems = 25` while `('A' ... 'ZZ').elems = 702`

Comment: I would say that's a bug. You should file it the Rakudo repo.

Answer (score 6):

see which code it is used: [rakudo/operators](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/e9351cbaa961c4d1e4ef8b4cb52418d55766a8d6/src/core/operators.pm6#L249)

your code is very similar to

```perl6
"A", *.succ ...^ * gt "AA"
```

(`"B" gt "AA"` is `True`)

and code by Curt Tilmes is similar to

```perl6
"A", *.succ ...^ {$_ gt "ZZ" or .chars > "ZZ".chars}
"A", *.succ ...^ {$_ gt "YY" or .chars > "YY".chars}
```

(`"Z" gt "YY"` and `"AAA".chars > "ZZ".chars` are `True` )